# How do I implement an Observer to get data from a listener?

Tags: java, android, firebase, observer-pattern, observable

I am using the [MaterialDrawer](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer) library to create a simple drawer for my app, some of the instances of classes in the library need a string passed into them when called. An example is the `IProfile` class:

`IProfile profile = new ProfileDrawerItem().withName("John Doe");`

where the `withName()` method takes in a string.

I have created a class `MyObservable.java` (extends Observable) class that I intend using to get data to be used in my `MainActivity` which has the MaterialDrawer library implemented. In this class, I have a method `implementData()` which has my listener for what I need from my firebase database.

This is what it looks like:

```
    public class MyObservable extends Observable {

    // Attach our firebase reference...
    Firebase userRef = new Firebase("https://myApp.firebaseio.com/users");
    AuthData authData;

    public String username = "";
    public String email = "";


    public void changeUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;

        setChanged();
        notifyObservers(username);
    }


    public void implementData(){
        // Get the authentication data of our user from the reference.
        authData = userRef.getAuth();

        // This is the listener I have to get the data from. 
        userRef.child(authData.getUid()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                UserSchema user = snapshot.getValue(UserSchema.class);
                // This guy needs to be used in the MainActivity appDrawer() method
                String userName = user.getName();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

            }
        });

    }
}

class MyObserver implements Observer {

    public void update(Observable observable, Object data) {
        // For now I just print it out to System.out
        System.out.println("Username:" + data);
    }
}
```

Then I notify my observers of the username change with the `changeUsername()` method:

```
public void changeUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;

        setChanged();
        notifyObservers(username);
    }
```

In the MyObservable class, I have a `MyObserver` class that implements `Observer` with the `update()` method called whenever an observer has been updated. In the `update()` method for now, I just print out the `username` of the user to ensure something is actually happening.

This is where I need the data from the observer (In the MainActivity):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ...

    public void appDrawer(){

        IProfile profile = new ProfileDrawerItem()

                // I need the user's data here
                .withName("Test")
                .withEmail("test@test.com")
                .withIcon(R.drawable.avatar2);
    }

    ...

}
```

I have spent hours trying to '**react**' to the events happening in the listener by trying to retrieve data to be used in my MainActivity but I'm not sure I'm using the Observable/Observer pattern properly, also since this is an Asynchronous event by Firebase to get data, using an Observer has been the best way to do this.

The `appDrawer()` method is called in my Activity's `onCreate()` .

How do I retrieve data from the Listener with an Observer, so I can use it elsewhere?

Answer (score 15):

I can't tell by your design what's really going on. Naming a class `Listener` then making it `Observable` seems counter-intuitive. A listener listens or observes. Nonetheless, it sounds like you have another class in the `Listener` that's an `Observer` so I'm a little lost but you seem unsure if you've implemented the pattern correctly. That I can clear up with an example.

```
public class MyObserver implements Observer {
    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
        System.out.println(arg + " " + ((MyObservable)o).name);
    }
}

public class MyObservable extends Observable {

    public String name = "Observable";

    public void changeMe(String word) {
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers(word);
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyObservable myObservable = new MyObservable();
        myObservable.addObserver(new MyObserver());
        myObservable.changeMe("Hello");
    }
}
```

The `update` method gives you the object you're observing as well as the arguments (the data you want shared with the observer) you passed into `notifyObservers()`. If you've done it like this then you should get the behavior you expect.

As you can see data can be sent to the observers that is outside or inside the observable. When you run it the output is...

> Hello Observable

Comment: `notifyObservers(String)` should be called from `changeMe()`.

Comment: @cybergen, "should be" is probably a little restrictive to me. It's public so it's purposely exposed. I would say in the general case calling `notifyObservers` in every method that changes the state can be excessive. I see your point though. In the OP's case it doesn't matter as there's only one notifying. I will edit it for your viewing pleasure and so it matches OP's code better.

Comment: Oh wow, thank you so much, so I can have the `changeMe` method return the string that is being updated instead and the observers don't have to be added inside the observable yeah?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I know what you mean because you say return and nothing is being returned here. If you mean "return" it to the observer then yes. You can push it up the chain by passing the string into `changeMe()` and then into `notifyObservers()`. @geek.x

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils can you please have a look at the updated code with the right names for the classes here but I'm still kinda confused: http://paste.ofcode.org/CdstbURUBbaZPmRhuVR2FN

Comment: @geek.x, if you look at my example you will see that it doesn't matter *how* you get the value to the observer. In your example you have a method which notifies the observers - good! - but you never call it. So, when the data changes, notify the observer. If you need your main activity to update the view right away, the main activity will need to be the observer or it will need an instance of an observer which it will be able to *pull* the *most up-to-date* username from it or be passed as a reference to it so it can update the view (I think :)).

Comment: @geek.x, I would encourage you to add the code from the link to your post so others will be more willing to chime in.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils thanks! I have updated the code now, but if I'm getting the data from the `onDataChange()` method, won't the data be null by the time time the `userName` is updated?  lol, damn I'm so lost.